# Select en modal no se refleja bien y sale detrás del modal - Angular > 11

Tags: angular

Estoy desarrollando en Angular con material indigo pink y los select funcionan bien los de la libreria pero cuando uso los select propios de angular material en un modal los `option`  se reflejan detrás del modal

Actualmente lo estoy usando asi para evitar el problema:

```
<mat-form-field class="col-sm-12">
   <mat-label>Area</mat-label>
      <select matNativeControl [(ngModel)]="userAdd.IdArea" name="IdArea" required>
         <option class="form-control" *ngFor="let area of areas" value="{{area.IdArea}}">
             {{area.area}}
          </option>
       </select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Necesito usarlo de la manera correcta para usar el auto complete y demás y toca como sale exactamente en la librería de material angular.

Cuando lo uso de esta manera es cuando me sale los option detrás  del modal como mostrare en la imagen.

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let area of areas"  [value]="area.IdArea" >{{area.area}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tal vez una solución rápida es colocar en `option`: `style="z-index: 99999;"` ¿Puedes probarlo?

Comment: @GusSL no ya puse eso de css y tampoco funciona